# Iterate through files ending with various extensions

Tags: python, regex, file, glob

I'm using this line of code to iterate through files ending with the .tar extension, using what I believe to be a regex character '*'.

```
for f in glob.glob('{}/{}/Compressed_Files/*.tar'.format(path, site_id)):
```

How can I do this same thing but also include files ending in the csv.gz extension? Using a regex or operator maybe?

Comment: Glob patterns are not regular expressions.

Comment: Oh, do you know what the '*' means in this context then? Because I've been using this to iterate over files ending in '.tar.' and it has been working

Comment: It's a wildcard that matches any number of any character, like the regex `.*`

Answer (score 0):

`glob` doesn't support patterns that can match multiple strings like that. Just combine two globs.

```
g1 = glob.glob('{}/{}/Compressed_Files/*.tar'.format(path, site_id))
g2 = glob.glob('{}/{}/Compressed_Files/*.tar.gz'.format(path, site_id))
for f in g1 + g2:
    # code
```

If there are lots of matches, it may be better to use `glob.iglob()`, which is an iterator. Then use `itertools.chain()` to combine them.

```
g1 = glob.iglob('{}/{}/Compressed_Files/*.tar'.format(path, site_id))
g2 = glob.iglob('{}/{}/Compressed_Files/*.tar.gz'.format(path, site_id))
for f in itertools.chain(g1, g2):
    # code
```

Comment: for scalability i would recommend generators instead of persisting glob results in lists

Comment: what are generators exactly?

Comment: @Devyl You mean `glob.iglob()`? I've updated the answer to mention them.

Comment: @View_user Google "python generators"

Answer (score 0):

with generator, will not cache all results, maybe there can be many files

```
def glob_patterns(patterns: list[str]):
    for pattern in patterns:
        for path in glob.iglob(pattern):
            yield path

for path in glob_patterns((
    '{}/{}/Compressed_Files/*.{}'.format(path, site_id, extension)
    for extension in ('tar', 'tar.gz')
)):
    print(path)
```

Comment: You should use `iglob()` to avoid storing each glob result.